# Create an object instance of a subclass from an external class

Tags: java, swing, subclass

I've created an application that attaches events to a class of JButtons and other swing components that I instantiate many times in the GUI class.

The class MenuItemEventHandler is attached to each menu item. This works perfectly fine when the MenuItemEventHandler class is external. However i need to get it inside the GUI class instead of external.

I'm left with the issue of not being able to reference the event handler subclass from another external class in the same package. Is it possible to do so?

Below is the guiclass and eventhandler subclass

```
public class GUIClass {

// gui behaviour

    public class MenuItemEventHandler extends AbstractAction {

      private String aVariable;

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          // update a JList with added item
      }
}
```

Below is the external class i want to reference to the event handler so i can attach it to the collection of GUI objects.

It's making reference to the MenuItemEventHandler class that i cant achieve.

```
public class MenuItem {

ResturantGUI.MenuItemEventHandler action = ResturantGUI.new MenuItemEventHandler(this.item);
newButton.setAction(action);

// attach the event to the menu item
```

Comment: This smells of being a possible [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Why do you state, `"However i need to get it inside the GUI class instead of external."`? Why must the class itself be internal? There's almost never an absolute need for this.

Comment: You say *i can't achieve*, but not why you can't or what problems you run into while trying.

Comment: Hello again, I'm trying to populate a DefaultListModel after a menu item fires the actionPerformed event. The issue resides where I don't know how i'd pass the data from the action performed event to the GUI without some overlap that causes tones of unnecessary objects to be created.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question, this time stating what your real problem is, with the model and all, which data needs to be passed to and fro, where the problems with passing it are. Your current question should just be part of the new version, showing what you thought would solve the problem, and where it breaks.

Comment: Okay thanks i'll do that.

Comment: Is it not possible though? I need to some how update the JList when the buttons action performed event is triggered.

Comment: Yes of course it's possible. Consider clarifying your question/code and even posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options, either you can make `MenuItemEventHandler` `static`:

so you declare your class like this:

```
public static class MenuItemEventHandler ...
```

or you create your event handler with a reference to an instance of the enclosing class `GUIClass`

Something:

```
GUIClass guiClass = new GUIClass();
MenuItemEventHandler handler = guiClass.new MenuItemEventHandler();
```

Personally, I find the second option usually the smell of a bad or incorrect design. I almost never use this kind of construction. Just an example of how you can "work around" this kind of pattern (there are others, it depends of the context):

```
public class GUIClass {
     public class MenutItemEventHandler {
           ...
     }

     public MenuItemEventHandler createEventHandler() {
           return new MenuItemEventHandler();
     }
}

...

 GUIClass guiClass = new GUIClass();
 MenuItemEventHandler handler = guiClass.createEventHandler();
```

Comment: Made the event handler static in the GUI class and changed the GUI class to a view which is instantiated in a separate class. Eclipse wanted me to change the field in my GUI for the DefualtListModel to static I also had to make it protected so that other classes don't have access to it but the eventhandler subclass can access the DefualtListModel in the gui. when is it okay to make fields of a class static?

Comment: @Machiinate Avoid static fields at all costs. Either the field is a constant and it should be `static final` either it should be an instance field. `static` fields are "evil" :-)